# Rule to add a font family but inherit the fallbacks

Tags: css, fonts

I want to make a rule that would apply to a lot of elements (maybe all elements), and would set one `font-family`. When this font family fails (which it will), I want the fallback font to be *whatever was set for the element in a previous rule.* Is this possible? Currently I have this, and it correctly applies the new font but when that font fails, there is no fallback (it just reverts to browser default).

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'iserif';
src: local('Comic Sans MS');
unicode-range: U+49;
}

* { font-family: 'iserif'; }
```

I assure you, I have a good reason to do this... and I promise I won't use Comic Sans in my final code :) (not that anyone would ever see it but me)

Desired result (for an element with Arial as the font if it weren't for this rule):

[image: screenshot]

Actual result:

[image]

Comment: does  

* { font-family: iserif, arial; } 

not work?

Comment: Yes, but the idea was that the author of this rule wouldn't know what the fallback is supposed to be (imagine it's in a different css file), and if the fallback is changed in the future (in the other css file) this change should be reflected in the result. AFAIK this simply isn't possible in CSS.. Just as well, my use case for it is long gone.

Comment: Also, the fallback typeface might be different for different elements (e.g. `<p>` vs `<h2>`) while this rule is intended to affect all elements with `*`.